# Fixing ugly string export in export_code for Scala

Tags: scala, isabelle

I hava a function `foo` that works on the `string` type. When I `export_code foo in Scala file -` I get a very ugly Scala code.

A very long listing, looking like this is created

```
abstract sealed class nibble
final case class Nibble0() extends nibble
final case class Nibble1() extends nibble
final case class Nibble2() extends nibble
...
```

Comment: Isabelle/HOL for Scala?!? Wow.

Comment: Isabelle has code generation for a number of languages, including Scala and Haskell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to import the `Code_Char` theory in order to tell code generation to use the existing implementations of char/string in the target language instead of a translation of the Isabelle definition as a datatype.

Add `"~~/src/HOL/Library/Code_Char"` to your theory's import clause and everything should work fine.

Also, I am told – but was unable to verify this so far – that this should always be at the end of your import clause, because otherwise, funny things happen to the code generator.

Cheers,
Manuel